# cursor fetch statement calling first row repetedly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cursor

Hi ,

i created a cursor with simple select statement which has only 10 rows
when i am going to print after while @@fetch_status=0 then it recursively 
call only first row,the execution did not stop.
i dont know why is getting display only first rows repetedly the cursor does not move to second row

```
  Here below is my code

  declare cur_data  cursor for

 select DISTINCT pkd.boxnumber  from packagedetail pkd
 inner join PalletDetail pld on pld.boxnumber=pkd.boxnumber
 INNER JOIN TRACKING T ON T.BOXNUM=PKD.SCANBOXID
 where pkd.shipmentlocation='NYWH' AND pld.shipmentnumber='SH0675535'

 declare @boxnumber NVARCHAR(50)

 open cur_data 

 fetch next from cur_data  into @boxnumber
 while @@fetch_status=0
 begin

 print @boxnumber

END
close cur_data
deallocate cur_data
```

Comment: you have to re-fetch within your while loop, otherwise you're never getting the next row

Comment: cursors are broadly despised by most as they are very inefficient -- they have their uses, but they are few and far between... you are likely better off using a different approach here, it just depends what you need done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to have a fetch ... next inside your while loop also ...

```
 ...
 open cur_data 
 fetch next from cur_data  into @boxnumber
 while @@fetch_status=0
 BEGIN
     print @boxnumber
     fetch next from cur_data  into @boxnumber
 END
 ...
```

Comment: when you run your select statement, how many rows does your query return? your cursor syntax seems to be ok...